# Progress dialog on Google map until current location is not shown

Tags: android, google-maps, progressdialog

- I want to show progress bar during Google map loading
- Progress bar until Google map focused on my current location
- I want to display progress dialog like below image

[image]

Code :

-- Camera focus on current location

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
                if (location != null)
                {
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 19));

                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                            .zoom(19)                   // Sets the zoom
                            .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                                           // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Comment: i guess u have network and GPS check before trying to find current location.. after that you use LocationManager.NetworkProvider instead of best criteria.. Becoz most of the time, the criteria gives u a GPS. its not a good option.. Also have a progressBar and put this line of code **mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);**  and visibility to visible before calling get location in onMapReady and once the location is not null make visibility GONE.. this should help

Comment: but how to show progress bar until map is loded ?

Comment: First of all do not use your own location manager when you can use the FusedLocationApi. This API has callbacks for when it is connected and from that you can get the latest Lat/Lng coordinates.
A Google mapView has callbacks that notifies you when the map is ready and loaded.

Comment: how to show progress dialog ? simple question

Comment: sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your xml where u have ur map; declare a progress bar, like this; intially its visibility will be gone(mean it will be hidden):

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Then initialize ur progressbar in the activity where ur displaying ur map; declare it as a class variable:

```
mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
```

Then in the oncreate of ur map activity set the visibility of the progressbar to visible:

```
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Then at the place where ur calling gmap.AnimateCamera(i.e when ur zooming) where location is not null if clause; u set the visibility to gone:

```
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**Enjoy**

Comment: can u help me one more time. I want to set background of progress bar to transparent.. i.e. only circle should be visible

Comment: my internet doesn't seem to work.. i'll reply once if its trobleshooted